# Invalid PE File x64dbg

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, ida

I am trying to open a simple Hello World program written in c++ in x64dbg and I get an error "Invalid PE File". The file loads fine in IDA. What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of x64dbg here, the error you're experiencing is misleading and has nothing to do with the validity of the PE file. It simply means that `CreateProcess` failed for your file. This can have various reasons, once of which is the validity of the PE file. Get the latest version from [here](http://releases.x64dbg.com) for a better error message.

Validate the process starts correctly outside of the debugger and make sure it is not blocked by for example your anti virus software.

Comment: I am encoutering this problem right now. With the last version (2019-05-19_18-24).

Comment: Probably because your executable doesn’t start on Windows either.